# Get only ASCII values from byte-encoded python string with hex characters

Tags: python-3.x, hex, ascii, decode, encode

When I am trying to get data from a table in redshift and create a CSV file from it but while doing it I am facing a problem with bytes.

```
b'INTERLEAVED\xff\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00varchar\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I need only INTERLEAVED from that bytes data. i have tried by doing decoding but the result is still in bytes format even after performing decode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the bytes in your bytestring that can be interpreted as an ASCII printable character, you can use (assuming `bstr` is your bytestring)

```
newstr = ''.join(chr(b) for b in bstr if 32 <= b < 128)
```

That results in the string

```
'INTERLEAVEDvarchar'
```

We did get more characters than you expected. If you really want only the upper-case characters you could instead use

```
newstr = ''.join(chr(b) for b in bstr if ord('A') <= b < ord('Z'))
```

or

```
newstr = ''.join(chr(b) for b in bstr if 'A' <= chr(b) <= 'Z')
```

or perhaps

```
newstr = ''.join(chr(b) for b in bstr if chr(b) in 'ABCDEFGJIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
```

Any of those result in the string

```
'INTERLEAVED'
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
fixed_sample = sample.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Comment: When i tried to do that I am getting a error 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I think as the data is already in bytes format it cant be encoded again

Comment: @gireeswarreddy you need to change it to string first as the comment above suggested. you can do sample.decode("utf-8").decode('ascii', 'ignore'). let me know if it works